# Deployment of React.js and Node.js Web app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm building a web app using React.js and Node.js. I wanted to know that how I deploy my web application on a server? Like when I run it on my local server then it needs two server, one is for React.js and another is for Node.js. Is it goes same with deployment also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will only need one server (unless you're using a server side rendering framework like Next.js). If you used create-react-app, use should be able to run `npm build` and it'll create a static build.
Here's some relevant links:

- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/
- https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#use-the-production-build

Comment: No Problem. Lemme know if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

You need to run script to build and bundle your client side by calling `npm run build` in terminal, then you should serve those build files in index/main file in backend side .
Then you can deploy your application.
You can read this awesome article to understand in depth:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/deploying-a-mern-application-using-mongodb-atlas-to-heroku/